# manifest.json commands curly brace closing problem

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, manifest, manifest.json

I have my manifest.json file that is not loading.

It was loading before this, but as soon as I add the shortcut Shift + A in the commands section, it stops working:

[image: screenshot]

Don't know what mistake I'm making. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use any json validator online or paste whole json

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: The other user is probably right. most likely, you messed up your JSON file somehow. A) you might want to include that file here or B) just use a good text editor that checks such things.

Comment: comments not working in json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check line number 33, where you have commented open brace but the corresponding closing brace is still active in line 38.
Hope this will solve your problem.